# Redirect domain based on regular expression

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to change domains when I have a certain path on the URL request. More specifically I need to identify first if a certain path (`/path`) exists on the URL of the request.

If it exists then show the website with the domain `www.mynewdomain.com/path/`. If `/path` does not exist on the URL of the request then show `www.myolddomain.com` or whatever the request will be.

Comment: Do you want to keep the parameters to that request as is? I mean let us say, you access using http://www.myolddomain.com/resource/path?query=sachin, do you want to redirect it as http://www.mynewdomain.com?query=sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RewriteRule to redirect the request to the new domain. You can mention the config in the virtual host.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /path(.*) http://www.mynewdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This configuration retains the URL part after the `/path` token [ denoted by `(.*)` ] and is rewritten to the redirected path using `$1`.